# Is the EDM of a fundamental particle T-odd?

Tags: symmetry, time, dipole-moment

Is the EDM of a fundamental (or almost) particle (e.g. electron, neutron) T-odd? On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_electric_dipole_moment) it says that it is not (check the diagram). But I found some papers (e.g. [this review](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/pdf/10.1103/RevModPhys.91.015001?casa_token=ti75fu-F4EgAAAAA%3Ab7g9s4a--xqL_xBsVwxBPWD9d1XOciFMOD6YZ1OSR0G7GisrgNcoTpwOcvYxvGWUedi2Y_P0qYJtta0) and the references within) which claims that the EDM is T-odd (check the second page). I am confused now. Of course I trust that paper (more than 100 citations) over Wikipedia, but I was wondering, am I miss-understanding something? Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: What diagram? [this one](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:NEDM_P%26T_violation.png#mw-jump-to-license)?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty yes that one. And mainly equations 1,2 and 4 in the paper.

Comment: Consider to spell out  acronyms.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the diagram that you refer to, can be very misleading, because it does not do a great job of describing how the EDM transforms.

The electron EDM is a P-odd and T-odd object. It induces a P-even and T-odd vector quantity in atoms that couple to the P-odd T-even electric field. This finally creates a term in the atomic Hamiltonian that is again P-odd and T-odd.

The reason why the eEDM is T-odd, is that it necessarily needs to be proportional to the spin of the electron (which is T-odd). If the EDM vector would be seperate of the spin, it would mean that the electron would have another quantum number and that would be immediately visible through the Pauli principle.